# ios - sqlite retrieved parametrized sql statement

Tags: ios, sql, sqlite

I am using the following code to create an `sql` statement for `sqlite` in `ios`.

```
if(addStmt == nil) {
        const char *sql = "insert into product(product_id, product_name,quantity)     Values(?, ?, ?)";
        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &addStmt, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
            NSAssert1(0, @"Error while creating add statement. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
    }


sqlite3_bind_int(addStmt, 1,  12 );
sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 2, [@"iphone" UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
sqlite3_bind_int(addStmt, 3,  3 );


const char *sqlSt=sqlite3_sql(addStmt);
NSString *str=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s",sqlSt];
```

I get

`insert into product(product_id, product_name,quantity) Values(?, ?, ?)` 
as output.

How can I get something like

`insert into product(product_id, product_name,quantity) Values(12, "iphone",3)` ?

Comment: What do you need this for?

Comment: @CL I am going to execute the statement on a remote `mysql` server.

Comment: SQLite has [functions to format strings in SQL](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/mprintf.html). However, a better idea would be to make the remoting protocol accept parameters, or to not use SQL in the protocol at all.

Answer (score 0):

SQLite does not have any mechanism to read back the values of parameters.